# Preserve left table in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please consider this script:

```
declare @Days   table
([Day]  int)

insert @Days values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

declare @Data table
(
   ID       int,
   [Day]    int,
   [Name]   Nvarchar(50),
   [Status] bit
) 

insert into @Data
values(1,1,'Nima',1),(2,2,'Arian',1),(3,2,'Nima2',0),(4,2,'Nima3',1),(5,3,'Nima4',0)

select y.[Day],count(Id) 
from @Days y left join @Data d 
  on y.[Day] = d.[Day]
where Status=1
group by y.[Day]
```

this query has this result:

```
Day (No column name)
1   1
2   2
```

but I want this result:

```
Day (No column name)
1   1
2   2
3   0
4   0
5   0
```

How I can rewrite above query to get above result.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition in the `where` clause to the condition for the `left join`. As the query is written now the `where` clause filters out rows with null values (and turns the left join into an inner join).

```
select y.[Day],count(Id) 
from @Daye y 
left join @Data d on y.[Day] = d.[Day] and d.Status=1
group by y.[Day]
```

Comment: Great! . But can you explain this sql server behavior?

Comment: @Kerezo For the rows that don't have matches in the left join the _status_ column value will by null. The where clause is applied after the join and thus will filter out the null values. By making it part of the join condition the left join will return all rows from the left side plus those matching both the day and status conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the `group by` clause to the `@Data` table only, and left join that result on the `@Daye` table:

```
SELECT    y.[Day], count(Id) 
FROM      @Daye y 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   [Day], COUNT([Id]) AS cnt
           FROM     @Daye
           WHERE    [Status] = 1
           GOURP BY [Day]) d ON y.[Day] = d.[Day]
```